# question about a dot product

Tags: analysis

Let 
$$w(t)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } 0\le t\le \frac{1}{2}\\2t-1 &\text{ if }\frac{1}{2}\le t\le 1 \end{cases}$$

Is 
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} w(t)f(t)g(t)dt$$ 
a dot product on $C^1[0,1]$ ?

Why and how to prove it? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @jenny: I edited the question for you, let me know if is ok.

Comment: thats perfect thanks you so much !

Comment: Have you tried checking whether the inner product axioms hold?

Comment: More or less one just has to check the properties which an inner product (dot product) has. Which one is difficult to see? Linearity in the first (or second) part follows from the properties of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** a dot product. One of the properties of such a product is that $\langle f,f\rangle = 0$ if and only if $f = 0$. Let

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases} \left(\dfrac12 - t\right)^2 & : t \leq \dfrac12 \\
 0 & : t > \dfrac12 \end{cases}
$$

so $f \neq 0$. What is $\langle f, f\rangle$?

(Note: this fulfills the other requirements though: it is symmetric, it is linear, and it is positive **semi**-definite ($\langle f,f \rangle \geq 0$))

Comment: This does not belong to $C^1[0,1]$.

Comment: One has to take a smooth function which has the support in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: @BaronVT The function must be in $C^1[0,1]$!

Comment: err, yes. Sorry for the carelessness, it should be fixed now. The main point is, there are no shortage of arbitrarily smooth functions supported in the first half of the interval, any of which provide a counterexample.

Comment: @BaronVT is tour f(t) is corect with the interval [0,1/2] and 0 for [1/2,1]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

it cannot be an inner product. take a function $f$ that is $1$ on $[0,1/2]$ and zero elsewhere and smooth it our over a small interval about $x = 1/2$. the norm of the function is zero but the function is not.